# Absolute value equality of variables in MATLAB optimization

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to solve an optimization problem using either MATLAB's built-in `linprog` function, or with MATLAB CVX front-end. These tools provide an easy way to model constraints such as `A.x <= B`, `Aeq.x == Beq`, and `a <= x <= b`.

I know for sure that some of my variables should have identical absolute values. Let's say `|x1| = |x2|`. What is the best way to model this constraint ?

Comment: If your constraint is in absolute values, then your problem is not linear. Not sure about convex programming tools though.

Comment: If you don't have too many of those, you might want to run each branch independently: `x2 = x1`, and `x2 = -x1` and reduce the variable count by one.

Comment: Sure, but I can't do that for 2 reasons. The first one is the one you mentioned (unknown number of those, also sometimes more than two are equal), and the other one is that both variables are used in the constraints. Let's say `u1` and `u2` are vectors, I have constraints of the form `u1' * x + u2' * x == 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a convex problem, hence it cannot be solved directly with the tools you mention.

It is inherently combinatorial, in the sense that you can enumerate cases based on the sign of the two variables, and for every such case, a linear equality holds. Hence, you can either solve the problem by simply solving a linear program for every case and pick the best solution, or represent the cases using binary variables and logic modelling. Since you mentioned cvx and linprog, you are in MATLAB, and I can then give you the code to implement the model in YALMIP instead  (disclaimer, developed by me), which automatically will model the non-convex equality through by introducing binary variables and  suitable disjunctions

```
x = sdpvar(n,1)
Model = [A*x <= b, Aeq*x == beq, abs(x(1))==abs(x(2)), a<= x <= b]    
optimize(Model)
```